# .load to call 'facebook like box' is breaking jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, facebook

I am seeing some strange behavior when trying to call "**facebook like box**" with Ajax.

The idea is for a user to click a button. `Onclick`, the facebook plugin will be called with `.load()` and appear. `Onclick` again, the content will disappear.

The reason for doing this is to cut down on HTTP requests at page load. Is this the best way to achieve such?

The code I have written works perfectly with another function calling a weather page. So im thinking it could be something to do with the facebook plugin breaking the jquery/function?

Here is my JS fiddle of the code; http://jsfiddle.net/aynzA/2/

You can see the code working for "weather" in the footer of my site at, r.adamtoms.co.uk

```
<style>.loader{background-color:red;margin: 30px 0;}</style>
    <ul>    
        <li class="facebook-f">
            <div class="footer-text">
                <a href="#" onclick="return false;">Facebook</a>
            </div>
            <div class="fb-loader-content"><br>loading wheel</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="facebook-content" style="display: none;"></div>

    $(".facebook-f").click(function () {
        if (!$(".facebook-content").is(':visible')) {
            $('.fb-loader-content').addClass('loader');
            alert('class added')
            $('.facebook-content').load("http://www.google.com", function () {
            alert('loaded google, now remove loading wheel')
                $('.fb-loader-content').removeClass('loader');
            });
            $('.facebook-content').toggle();
        } else {
            $('.facebook-content').toggle();
        }
    });
```

Really appreciate some feedback on this. And please excuse my naivety, I'm new to this.

Comment: I found on another page someone with a similar problem. They were advised to add, FB.XFBML.parse( ); after .load().
I have tried this which now makes it hang on the loader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @LowerClassOverflowian counter method and a "closure" I managed to make something that works.

Here is the code:

```
var element = document.getElementById("facebook-f");

element.onclick = (function () { "use strict";

// init the count to 0
var count = 0;

return function(e) {
    //count
    count++;

if (count === 1) {    // do something on first click
    $('.fb-loader-content').addClass('loader');
    $('.facebook-content').load("templates/include/scripts/facebook.php", function () {
        $('.fb-loader-content').removeClass('loader');
    });
} 
if (count > 1) {
    $('.facebook-content').slideToggle(200);
}
};

}) ();
```

cheers everyone that helped. If you have any further suggestions please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your website in your browser's console, you see the following errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier (index):62
Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined core.js:66
Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id. all.js:56
FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init(). all.js:56
```

I'm guessing that "Invalid App Id" has something to do with the reason it's not working.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jack.
Thats now appearing as I have added 'FB.XFBML.parse( );' after the .load() as was suggested here: stackoverflow.com/questions/6345787/jquery-load-will-break-facebook-like-button-comment-box-how-to-workaround

any idea how to put this right?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have found a work around. I changed the :visible to :hidden and removed the style="display:none;" from the facebook-content div. Seems to have done the job.

```
<ul>    
    <li class="facebook-f">
        <div class="footer-text">
            <a href="#" onclick="return false;"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="fb-loader-content"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="facebook-content"></div>

$(".facebook-f").click(function () {
    if (!$(".facebook-content").is(':hidden')) {
        $('.fb-loader-content').addClass('loader');
        alert('class added')
        $('.facebook-content').load("http://www.google.com", function () {
        alert('loaded google, now remove loading wheel')
            $('.fb-loader-content').removeClass('loader');
        });
        $('.facebook-content').toggle();
    } else {
        $('.facebook-content').toggle();
    }
});
```